# Defining a stack array of registers

Tags: c++, templates, sse

In a performance-critical C++ function I want to use SSE intrinsics to handle some values. This function has an integer template argument `N` that can take the values 1 to 4, and that gives the number of XMM registers that I need.

I could write this function four times and I would solve the problem; however, the function is pretty large and I would like to make it well maintainable by avoiding code duplication. What I need is something like

```
__m128d x[N];
```

i.e. I want to have `N` distinct `__m128d` variables as if I instantiate a stack array of them, but the code above does not work, as it creates a stack array of doubles and "maps" it to some XMM registers.

In other words, I would like to do a loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    k = _mm_add_pd(x[i], k);
}
```

(this is just an example, the actual code is a lot more complex), which is nicely optimized by the compilers I'm using, but the expression `x[i]` is not exactly what I want: the generated code reads it from the memory, while I want to have persistent values in the XMM registers without reads/writes from/to the main memory.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is `x[0]` ever dependent on `x[1]`? Or is the case `N=3` simply "do the same thing independently to all `x[i]`"?

Comment: In which sense you mean "dependent"? By going from N to N+1 one increases the accuracy of the function, and the value in x[i+1] will be kind of a "remainder" of the operation whose value is in x[i]. If you are asking whether the iterations of the example loop could be parallelized, no: in order to fill x[i+1] I need the value just stored into x[i], as x[i+1] represents the next "level" of accuracy wrt to x[i].

Comment: I have been playing around a bit with this scenario in [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) (extremely useful tool, it's an instant online assembly generator with lots of available compilers), but couldn't come up with a satisfactory solution to your problem. Are you sure the superfluous stores are a big performance problem?

Comment: An array doesn't work?
You could define x1, x2, x3, x4, then using a bunch of "if (N > 1) ..." statements, control which "Xn" variables are used. The compiler should eliminate all the extra code when N is < 4 because each of these IF's is evaluating a constant expression. You don't get to use loops either - but depending on the code, maybe you could write a recursive template.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are optimizations turned on? Is it possible that you have register pressure in your more complicated loop kernel that is preventing the compiler from keeping the array stores in registers? Are you building for 32 or 64 bit? Remember that there are only 8/16 XMM registers available in each mode. If you want to keep 4 values in registers at all times, that doesn't leave much room for temporaries.

Comment: @us2012: many thanks for the link; it seems to be a great tool. Yes, the stores and loads are a problem for me in this case.

Comment: @joeking: that's my current solution; I was looking for something more elegant. Since I must perform multiple similar loops, I have to put a lot of ifs.

Comment: @Jason: currently gcc, but the code is targeted for icc and otrher compilers too. 64 bit, optimization -O3. and the whole function uses no more than 12 registers. Temporaries are not a problem, the code compiles and runs fine.

Comment: @Spiros I don't suppose that writing the function 4 times is bad enough to warrant the use of something as unwieldy as Boost Preprocessor Metaprogramming ( http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/preprocessor.html ) ?

Answer (score 1):

The usual and obvious way to do it is to use preprocessor. You probably know about ## thing:

```
#define inc(n) x##n++

inc(1)
inc(2)
```

Another possibility are templates and inline functions. C++ compilers usually are very smart about inlining as much as possible, they even can put into registers fields of large structure. The only thing they don't like are those arrays, probably because their contents may be overwritten via aliased pointers. You may try to disable pointer aliasing, but i doubt it will help